# Can't start tests only for specific folder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

In my android app I has many Espresso's tests.
It's locate in:

```
/app/src/androidTest/kotlin/com/myproject/android/folder1/
```

and
/app/src/androidTest/kotlin/com/myproject/android/folder2/

To run all instrumented tests I use this:

```
gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest
```

Here output:

```
10:44:37 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Task :common:connectedAndroidTest

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 43s
97 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 8 from cache, 64 up-to-date
```

Nice.
But I need to start test only in `folder2`. I use this:

```
    gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.myproject.android.activity.*

but I get error:

04:45:23 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> Could not generate test report to '\app\build\reports\androidTests\connected'.
```

Comment: What is output of running command 'gradlew connectedAndroidTest'?

Comment: Log shows 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7m 43s'. only when you pass arguments it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package instead of class in the test arguments
gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=com.myproject.android.packageName

Comment: gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.package=com.company.myproject.android.activity.transitions - 

   And now run all  tests ONLY in folder "transitions". Nice.